# Angular *ngFor only showing 1 data item

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some data which I need to list using `ngFor` like this:

```
 <ul *ngFor="let dat of data; let i = index">
   <li>{{ dat[i].name }} - {{ i }}</li>
 </ul>
```

The problem with the code above is it's only showing 1 item.

But I know that the items are there because when I do this:

```
  {{ dat[0].name }}

  {{ dat[1].name }}
```

The above gives me different items as expected but when I try to loop like this:

```
  {{ dat[i].name }}
```

It will only show the first one.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To iterate using `ngFor`, no need to add index. Replace `dat[i].name` with `dat.name`

Try this:

Since it is unclear the format of data, there are 2 possibilities:

For,

```
 data = [
    { name: "one" },
    { name: "two" }
  ]

 <ul *ngFor="let dat of data; let i = index">
   <li>{{ dat.name }} - {{ i }}</li>
 </ul>
```

For,

```
 data = [
    [
      { name: "one" },
      { name: "two" }
    ]
  ]

 <ul *ngFor="let dat of data[0]; let i = index">
   <li>{{ dat.name }} - {{ i }}</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Console returns something like this: [Array(2)]
0: Array(2)
  0: { name: "one" },
  1: { name: "two" }

Comment: I am unable to understand the array, Please add `{{data | json}}` in HTML, copy the result and add it in the comment

Answer (score 0):

From what you're presenting, `data` is a 1-element array, it's `dat` (`data`'s element) that has length (so, `data` would be something like `[[obj1, obj2, obj3]]`, instead of `[obj1, obj2, obj3]`). Hence you should iterate over's `data`'s 0-th - and only - element, like this:

```
<ul *ngFor="let dat of data[0]; let i = index">
```

Answer (score 0):

if data it's array, you dont need use [i] on iterable elems dat. use only dat.name